# ESAPI Validator.isValidInput() isn't matching backslashes

Tags: java, esapi

I'm trying to make an ESAPI validator that matches the following: alphanumerics, spaces, and **" # & ' ( ) + , . / \ : ; @ -**.

I've added this line to ESAPI.properties:

```
Validator.SiteNameString=^[a-zA-Z0-9 "#&'()+,./\\\\:;@-]+$
```

The data:

```
Site.name = "Site\\name \"#&'()+,./:;@-"
```

The call returns false:

```
ESAPI.validator().isValidInput("U_SITE_NAME", site.getName(), "SiteNameString", 100, true);
```

It works with everything else but the backslash.

I've tested other solutions I've found here and none of them worked.

On Kevin's advice I debugged the code and got this result:

Inside the DefaultValidator.isValidInput() call is a call to getValidInput() which calls ESAPI.encoder().canonicalize(input); This throws an IntrusionException. "Multiple (2x) encoding detected in Site\\name "#&'()+,./:;@-" It never tries to apply the validation pattern.

So are double backslashes (double since backslash is the escape character) are not allowed in fields in validated HTML text fields?

Comment: A suggestion, not an answer...fire it up in a debugger and single-step through the ESAPI code. In particular, pay attention to what the Validation.SiteNameString looks like to ESAPI.

Comment: Inside the DefaultValidator.isValidInput() call is a call to getValidInput() which calls ESAPI.encoder().canonicalize(input); This throws an IntrusionException. "Multiple (2x) encoding detected in Site\\name "#&'()+,./:;@-"

It never tries to apply the validation pattern.

Answer (score 0):

This is just an unverified hunch, but I think I see what's going on now. By default, `Encoder.canonicalize()` will throw an `IntrusionException` if it thinks it detects either multiple (controlled by the property **Encoder.AllowMultipleEncoding**) or mixed (controlled by the property **Encoder.AllowMixedEncoding**) is found. The default `Codecs` that `Encoder.canonicalize()` considers are `HTMLEntityCodec`, `PercentCodec`, and `JavaScriptCodec`. I think the canonicalize() method that gets called scans the string, finds the '' and probably treating it as JavaScript encoded where it checks it via the `JavaScriptCodec`. (See the property **Encoder.DefaultCodecList** for details.) And thus if fails before it even checks the regex. Setting a breakpoint in the canonicalize() method and then stepping through the code from there should allow you to verify whether my hunch is correct. The way around it is you customize that. IIRC, there is some Javadoc in the `Validator` interface or the `DefaultValidator` class that explains how to do that. I'm up to my chin in other ESAPI issues for the moment so I can't provide a lot of assistance at the moment.

Comment: Yes, you are correct. We ended up removing backslash from the legal name characters for security reasons.